# How to run two Spring Boot JARs sequentially from a single batch file?

Tags: java, windows, spring-boot, batch-file, jar

I have two Spring Boot JAR files to execute sequentially. I'm attempting to run them through a batch file in Windows. However, just the first JAR starts; the second one does not.

I tried below mentioned commands to achieve the same.

Command 1)

```bash
java -jar application1.jar
java -jar application2.jar
```

Command 2)

```bash
java -jar application1.jar
pause
java -jar application2.jar 
pause
```

Command 3)

```bash
 java -jar application1.jar
/wait java -jar application2.jar
```

In all cases, only the first JAR starts, but second one doesn't. Am I missing something?

Comment: What does your Spring Boot JAR do? Is it a commandline runner that finishes shortly after starting, or is it a web application that continues running (and thus doesn't exit!)?

Comment: You could test if prefixing with `CALL` fixes the problem. `CALL java -jar application1.jar`. If this works, try a look at `where java`

Comment: What makes you think you need a batch file for this task? Those are simply executable files, not internal commands.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel It's a backend application that continues running.

Comment: Then you need to use `start` to launch, so the batch file can continue, otherwise it waits for the application to exit.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I tried this -> java -jar application1.jar start java -jar application2. Jar . However, still facing the same problem. Application 1 has a cron scheduled. Can this create any issue?

Comment: You need to use `start` on the **first** application (and likely also the second). Right now, you launch `java` directly from your batch file, that means it waits for `java` to exit, which doesn't happen as it is a server application, so the batch file never arrives on the line to launch the second application.

Comment: Adding start on first application worked. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can try the windows start command, something like below:

```
start java -jar application1.jar
start java -jar application2.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

```
start java -jar application1.jar
java -jar application2.jar
```